# How to use throw to create errors where there are none?

Tags: java, exception

The title may be a bit misleading, as I think I know how to do this. However it is related.

i'm learning exception handling, and am writing a program that returns an error message if you try to calculate the square root of a negative number. I'd like to print an error message, but not include the rest of the default error message. For example:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Can't take square root of negative number
        at SqrtException.main(SqrtException.java:14)
```

Here's my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SqrtException {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double val;
        double root;


        System.out.print("Enter value: ");
        val = input.nextDouble();

        if(val < 0)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Can't take square root of negative number");
        }
        else
        {
            root = Math.sqrt(val);
            System.out.println(root);
        }     
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What don't you want to print out?

Comment: Anything in the error that isn't "Can't take square root of negative number"

Comment: You don't want the `at` line either?

Comment: No. I'd just like it to print the error message

Comment: All of the rest of that information is incredibly useful, even if that's not obvious in a trivial program like this. The stack trace (the second line) becomes indispensable once your program becomes larger. Removing useful information like that is a really bad idea in really all but the most corner of cases.

Comment: I realize all of that information is useful, it's helped me when i'm not trying to create an error. Perhaps i'm just going about printing something after an "error." I'm required to use `throw new ArithmeticException()`. I don't know if i'm just going about this the wrong way or not.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question. Sorry

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've figured it out. Thank you for the quick response.